# Relocating a sink on the perpendicular wall: any cons against running ABS through the walls back the the old drain?

Tags: plumbing

I am relocating a sink from one wall to the perpendicular wall and I want to know if there are any potential issue with this

I am wondering if instead of breaking the floor I could do this:
just run ABS across the walls (1) back to (2) which is the existing plubing for the old sink

It is too tedious to create the traps in the diagrams but assume they are there

[image]

this is the new layout (please ignore the green pipe you see at the left of the picture)
[image]

Comment: your shower drain appears to have no trap, that's not going to work well.

Comment: too tedious to create the traps in the diagrams but assume they are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you could, but read the applicable code: your run is very likely too long to be unvented. You'll need to vent this - run another dry vent pipe higher up and tie it to your newly proposed "white" vent stack.

Comment: the only white pipe there is the one connecting the shower, that is a drain not a vent
I am not sure where you are suggesting I should add a vent pipe> I can add a AAV under the sink in the new position. Would that work?

Comment: Forget about AAVs. They are regrettable abominations. There's a white vent pipe you propose to add in your other posting, on the other side of the drain stack (the gray vent is on the "wrong" side in this case). Anyway, just vent this properly. You have to and you won't regret doing it right. You're opening the walls **anyway**, so just run the drain and the vent pipes when you're there. Easy.

Comment: @MiniMe  the drain from the sink goes into a sanitary tee at the wall under the sink. The bottom of the tee is the drain and the top of the tee is the vent. Both pipes from the tee can be routed through the wall  to tie into existing or new drain and vent pipes.

Comment: @MiniMe This article illustrates why there is a length limit on the *trap arm,* the part of the drain pipe between the fixture trap and its vent.  If you exceed that limit, your drain may siphon all the water out of its trap and allow sewer gas to vent into your home.  AAVs can be applied to work around this limitation but your building official may not approve it in your proposed installation.  https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/maximum-length-for-fixture-drains_o

Comment: Thanks @JeffWheeler my design evolved please see my other threads posted here. I added adequate vents to the design and shortened that run

Comment: This is not a forum: there are no “threads”. Your question must stand on its own, and for it to be on topic it must be of use to other people. So changing circumstances are not really a hindrance: we speak of the question as it is on the site. Any of your situation is detached from the question that now lives its own life :) In general though if the circumstances change you may edit the question timely if there are no answers.